# PHP chgrp operation not permitted

Tags: php, apache, webserver

I have a bit PHP code that needs to change the group of files using `chgrp()`. The code worked on another server (php 5.2), but when migrated to a new server (php 5.3), it stopped working

> `chgrp()`: Operation not permitted.

I've double checked that the user account apache has write permissions to the file (and that it is the owner just to be doubly sure). I've also double checked that PHP `safe_mode` is off.

Any other tips?

Comment: is the group just created? sometimes you have to logout/login before new group take place

Comment: The groups already existed so it was just a matter of adding them to the apache user. The group thing was a bit a grasp at straws because I'm trying to change permissions on a file that apache itself created

Comment: I know this might throw a PalmToFaceException, but can you just double check that `file_exists()` returns true for the file?

Comment: yep I'm able to confirm that the file exists

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're trying to assign a group to the target file/directory that `apache` group is **not** a member of that, as it has mentioned in the [chgrp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php) documentation:

> Only the superuser may change the group of a file arbitrarily; other users may change the group of a file to any group of which that user is a member.

I'm not sure what's the idea behind it, but it says you should not be able to assign your files/directories to a group that you're not a member of them; therefor `apache` user can't assign any of its files/directories to most of the groups you might be thinking of (by default configuration).

P.S. You might be able to `chmod` and `chown` with the same privileges your `apache` user has, but again, it's not permitted to assign those files to another group that you're not a member of them.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue just stopped happening. I literally started adding some debug statements and was refreshing the logs when I added a new statement and then I noticed the error stopped showing up in the logs all of a sudden. I'm guessing something needed to be restarted and that happened in between my debugging. I'm not sure. But in theory safe_mode off, file exists, and apache user being owner/creator of the file should have worked from the start.